# How to add bottom navigator in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

Hello guys im new to flutter, and i wanted to ask how do i properly add bottom navigator to flutter? i've been tried few tutorials in youtube but there's always something that won't work.

so i want to ask you guys how to do it.

so this is gonna be the content i want my BottomNavigator to be in

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get_core/src/get_main.dart';
import 'package:get/get_navigation/get_navigation.dart';
import 'Reminder/ui/home_reminder.dart';
import 'Reminder/ui/widgets/button.dart';

void main() {
  // debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
  runApp(const HomePage());
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Medicine Reminder App'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Stack(
              children: [
                Image.asset(
                  'images/MenuImg.jpg',
                  width: 600,
                  height: 200,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Button 1'),
                  onPressed: () {
                     Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const ReminderHomePage()),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Button 2'),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Button 3'),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and the Button 1 would navigate to "ReminderHomePage"

```
import 'package:date_picker_timeline/date_picker_timeline.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/Reminder/services/notification_services.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/Reminder/services/theme_services.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/Reminder/ui/theme.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/Reminder/ui/widgets/add_remindbar.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/Reminder/ui/widgets/button.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/Reminder/ui/widgets/add_remindbar.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/home_page.dart';

class ReminderHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ReminderHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<ReminderHomePage> createState() => _ReminderHomePageState();
}

class _ReminderHomePageState extends State<ReminderHomePage> {
  DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.now();
  var notifyHelper;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    notifyHelper=NotifyHelper();
    notifyHelper.initializeNotification();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: _appBar(),
      backgroundColor: context.theme.backgroundColor,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          _addTaskBar(),
          _addDateBar(),
        ],
        ),
    );
  }
  _addDateBar(){
    return Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20),
            child: DatePicker(
              DateTime.now(),
              height: 100,
              width: 80,
              initialSelectedDate: DateTime.now(),
              selectionColor: Color(0xFFAAB6FB),
              selectedTextColor: Colors.white,
              dateTextStyle: GoogleFonts.lato(
                textStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    color:Colors.grey
                ),
              ),
              dayTextStyle: GoogleFonts.lato(
                textStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    color:Colors.grey
                ),
              ),
              monthTextStyle: GoogleFonts.lato(
                textStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    color:Colors.grey
                ),
              ),
              onDateChange: (date){
                    _selectedDate=date;
              },
            ),
          );
  }
  _addTaskBar(){
    return Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 5),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(DateTime.now()),
                      style: subHeadingStyle,
                      ),
                      Text("Today", 
                      style: headingStyle,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                MyButton(label: "Add Reminder", onTap: ()=>Get.to(AddReminderPage()))
              ],
            ),
          );
  }

  _appBar(){
    return AppBar(
      elevation: 0,
      backgroundColor: context.theme.backgroundColor,
      leading: GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){
            ThemeService().switchTheme();
            notifyHelper.displayNotification(
              title:"Theme Changed!",
              body: Get.isDarkMode?"Activated Light Theme!":"Activated Dark Theme!"
            );

            notifyHelper.scheduledNotification();
        },
        child: Icon(Get.isDarkMode ?Icons.wb_sunny_outlined:Icons.nightlight_round,
        size: 20,
          color:Get.isDarkMode ? Colors.white:Colors.black
        ),
      ),
      actions: [
        CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage: AssetImage(
            "images/profile.png"
          ),
        ),
        // Icon(Icons.person,
        // size: 20,),
        SizedBox(width: 20,),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

when i try tutorials from youtube, the background from "ReminderHomePage" always turns to blue, i dont know how that happen because when i run only "ReminderHomePage" the background is white.

any help would mean so much to me. thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should try this code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// This Widget is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: _title,
      home: BottomNavigatiobBarExample(),
    );
  }
}

class BottomNavigatiobBarExample extends StatefulWidget {
  BottomNavigatiobBarExample();

  @override
  _BottomNavigatiobBarExampleState createState() => _BottomNavigatiobBarExampleState();
}

class _BottomNavigatiobBarExampleState extends State<BottomNavigatiobBarExample> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const List<Widget> navigationItems = <Widget>[
    Text('Home Tab',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
    Text('Favorites Tab', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
    Text('Profile Tab',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title:  Text('Bottom Navigation Bar Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: navigationItems.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
            label: 'Favorites',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.people),
            label: 'Profile',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: hello sir, this bottomnavigator works perfectly, but as you can is in my "ReminderHomePage" code, i have a button that goes to "AddReminderPage", but after adding the bottomnavigator, the button to navigate to "AddReminderPage" doesnt work anymore, any way i can fix this sir? thank you

Comment: For `Get.to(AddReminderPage())` navigation you need to return `GetMaterialApp()` instead of `MaterialApp()` in main.dart.  Check https://pub.dev/packages/get Get package official documentation

Comment: hello sir, i already have GetMaterialApp() in my main.dart file.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ReminderHomePage()` class, change value of `backgroundColor` properties in `Scaffold` widget. You just need to change that backgroundColor values.

From

`backgroundColor: context.theme.backgroundColor`

to

`backgroundColor: Colors.white`

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: _appBar(),
      backgroundColor: context.theme.backgroundColor, /// change this one, example: Colors.white
      body: Column(
        children: [
          _addTaskBar(),
          _addDateBar(),
        ],
        ),
    );
  }
```